# error with Scope_Identity when trying to insert in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

```
 string cmdTrainText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Event_Train(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), Train," + 
                                "Barrel_Train, Fire_Truck, Tram, Beverage_Cart) " + 
                        "VALUES(cbTrain, cbTBarrelTrain, cbTFire_Truck, cbTram, " +
                               "cbTBeverage_Cart)";
```

I am getting the following error

> System.DataSqlClient.SqlException {"Incorrect syntax near '('."}

Everything compiles OK. I get this error when I run the Program.
I am using Visual Studio 2015. 
I am trying to learn C#

Do I need to put something around `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`?

Comment: If your intention is to provide a value for an existing identity field then the way to do that is to not give its name & not provide any value at all & the database will do it for you - i.e. remove SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: Putting SCOPE_IDENTITY() in the list of *target columns* is not valid, if the above is not the issue you need to explain what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScopeIdentity` should be the first element inside the `VALUES` brackets and you then you have to write the column name instead at the first brackets! `ScopeIdentity` in this case seems to be a value and not a column name for me.

An edit would look like this (with proposed column name `ScopeID`):

```
string cmdTrainText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Event_Train(ScopeID, Train," + 
                              "Barrel_Train, Fire_Truck, Tram, Beverage_Cart) " + 
                      "VALUES(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), cbTrain, cbTBarrelTrain, cbTFire_Truck, " +
                              "cbTram, cbTBeverage_Cart)";
```

Comment: [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: @downvoter -- please consider telling me your concerns about my answer, so I can improve it!!

Comment: What I am trying to do is update the Event_Train table based on the primary key of Customer table. Event_Train foreign key reference Customer table primary key. I have tried putting the ID  and you suggested however now I get can not insert null into ID

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a different number of values vs. number of fields; you have 6 fields and only 5 values.  Furthermore, if you have an IDENTITY field the db will autoincrement it without your specifying a value for it.  The SCOPE_IDENTITY is a return value to provide the last IDENTITY value generated by the db for your insert and for the scope of the action (read up on [IDENTITY vs. SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql)).